Showing icon of modifier but not of question asker
The below makes Emil Jerabek look like a crank. Just wanted to draw attention to this, specifically to the icon of the person who modified the question being shown, but not the icon of the question asker. I don't know if anyone will care or if the change would be easy to make, but just wanted to point it out.

Yes, I know it says "modified", but it still looks confusing to the eye.

Already reported on Meta Stack Exchange: "Newest Questions" tab showing last active user instead of the asker

@AndrewT. Thanks!
